# seekbar chnage pointer position at runtime

Tags: pointers, position, seekbar

Hi I am new to android,
 I want to change the seekbar pointer position to some custom value when user scroll seekbar pointer.
My seekbar positions are 1,2,3,4,5,7,10,15,20,30,60 and last max value is 100.

Comment: As a side note, make sure you include android tag because it'll help get you more views and thus quicker/better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has what you need
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5954

You can check instructions on how to install and use it. Min SDK is 15.

Comment: Hi,I want to set seekbar min value(2) and then step values increement by 2 till 22. max value .